# changing column names in pandas ( Index does not support mutable operations- )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this current column name:

```
print(common_nodes_df.columns[0])
('0', '1')
```

but when I try to change it to:

```
common_nodes_df.columns[0] = 1
```

I get this error:

```
Index does not support mutable operations
```

What could I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace the whole column names. In your case,

```
df.columns = [1] + list(df.columns[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.rename({'1': 1}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

1. use replace
   OR
2. while changing the name use inplace = True